# How to correctly use transactions in asp.net core with EF core and Azure SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

#### Background

In a rather small asp.net core web api app there is a connection to Azure SQL server using EF core. In one of the actions (in a web api controller) I'm doing a read and update operation on one row (the table always has one row!). There, either I end up in multiple threads reading the same value or deadlocks when using isolation level serializable.

#### Code

So this is how the code currently looks like. There is a controller that gets the context injected. In the action method this context is used to create a transaction, read a value using `Select(...).FirstOrDefault()` and afterwards update it using `Update(...)`. Later the changes are saved and the transaction is committed. I already use `IsolationLevel.Serializable`.

```
public ShortUrlController(LatestShortUrlContext latestShortUrlContext) 
{
    _context = context;
    _latestShortUrlContext = latestShortUrlContext;
}

...

// GET api/s/?url=...
[Route("api/s")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Register([FromQuery] string url) 
{
    using (var transaction = _latestShortUrlContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)) 
    {
        try 
        {
            var latestShortUrl = _latestShortUrlContext.LatestShortUrl.Select(s => s).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("Latest short URL is " + latestShortUrl);

            // ... some processing here, afterwards, update the url again

            _latestShortUrlContext.LatestShortUrl.Update(latestShortUrl);
            _latestShortUrlContext.SaveChanges();

            transaction.Commit();

            return Ok(newShortUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            transaction.Rollback();

            return StatusCode(404, e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

For the sake of completeness, here is how the context is created.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var con = string.Format("..");

    services.AddDbContext<LatestShortUrlContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(con));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Without the transaction related code I run into the problem that multiple threads read the same value and therefore make a wrong update on the table. With the transaction handling in place 8 out of 10 requests end up in a deadlock. (running JMeter with 10 parallel threads). Exception in case of the deadlock:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy. ---> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 105) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

#### Actual Question

Why are there deadlocks even though I use serializable transactions? Is it used wrong somehow? Is there another way in asp.net core + web api + Azure SQL Server to achieve the described behavior?

Comment: There are deadlocks *because* you use serializable transactions. That's the most restrictive transaction level. You don't need the transaction either, SaveChanges uses a transaction internally

Comment: Some strange code too -`Select(s => s)` is a no-op while `FirstOrDefault()` returns a *random* entry, not the latest one. Unless you specify an order, the server will whichever row is read first. In a single-core machine that *may* be the oldest one

Comment: And `LatestShortUrl.Update()` isn't needed since the entity is already being tracked. `SaveChanges()` will update it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Why does serializable transactions cause deadlocks? My (obviously wrong) assumption is that the table is locked in this case (only one row) when the row is read from the table. Then, only after the commit the lock is released. Until that time, all other transactions have to wait and then the next one (whoever is first) will be able to read that row.

Comment: you are confusing the transaction level with the row lock hint. Serializable means that the server will *prevent* anything that could change the rows *or* the results while the transaction is open. To do so, it has to take restrictive locks at the page and table level too. If you *don't* need a transaction, *don't* use a transaction

Comment: As for deadlocks, they occur the same way they always occur -  one request reads one row, another reads another row, for some reason they then try to modify it and have to wait forever for that UPDATE lock

Comment: In your case, `FirstOrDefault()` probably returns the same row to every request. All transactions start with a Read lock on that single row, then *all* try to take an Update lock to modify it and get blocked because it has shared locks by every other request. The server detects this and kills all other requests except one

Comment: Right... that's what the problem is. Even though there is a Serializable isolation level, read is still allowed. That's why multiple threads can have a Read lock on that one row. Makes sense. Guess I need to implement some concurrency handling in C# then... Thanks.

Comment: BTW implementing a queue over a database table is *very hard*. You can't just ask for the earliest or latest entry. If you search, you'll find various implementations that actually *delete* the queued entry, and use specific locking hints to avoid deadlocks. You *can't* have a non-destructive queue over a table

Comment: no that's not a problem, that's what it's there for. And no, you don't need to implement concurrency in C#, you'll only make things worse. You don't even need it for a simple update. Transactions don't work the way you assumed. Read about optimistic vs pessimistic concurrency if you want. Pessimistic is rarely used. If you want *queueing* though, you should probably look for non-DB solutions

Comment: Looking at your last two comments I'm not sure we're talking about the same here. There is one asp.net webapi app that accesses a SQL server where there is one table with exactly one row (and always only one row). Multiple parallel requests to that web api are triggered. They all want to read that one row and update it. Let's say the row just contains a number. And every request increases the number by 1 (let's say I want to count the number of requests). That's why I want to make sure that read and update is done together and all other requests have to wait.

Comment: then don't use an ORM. What you ask is a simple `UPDATE SET Counter=Counter +1 where SomeID=123`. Such an operation doesn't involve *entities* so it doesn't need an ORM. This would take only a single UPDATE lock on the target row

Comment: BTW T-SQL has bult-in support for [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) objects. You may not need a table at all for what you want to do

Comment: It's unfortunately a bit more complicated then just adding 1 :) This was just an example that describes the problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right. the code above just doesn't make sense, even for the scenario described. I took some fresh air now and totally changed the way the increment is done. No transactions needed. Thanks again.